# how do i build a list of maps in terraform

Tags: loops, terraform

i would like to build a list of maps in terraform. Is there an operation that would let me do that.

eg: i would like to build the structure (from aws_instance.test.*.private_ip)

```
addresses = [
   {
     address = private_ip-1
   },
   {
     address = private_ip-2
   }
   ...
]
```

Comment: Why? what you're asking is likely not possible, but what you're trying to do may be doable a different way. You you ask about what you're actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 6):

Apologies if this has already been resolved, I see that it's an older question.

I'm not sure if this is best practice, but this is the way I would attempt to reach the desired state.

Using the [null_resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/null_resource.html) you'd be able to do the following:

```
variable "addresses" {
  type = "list"

  default = [
    "private_ip-1",
    "private_ip-2",
    "private_ip-3"
  ]
}

resource "null_resource" "test" {
  count = "${length(var.addresses)}"

  triggers {
    address = "${element(var.addresses, count.index)}"
  }
}

output "addresses" {
  value = "${null_resource.test.*.triggers}"
}
```

And have this output:

```
Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

addresses = [
    {
        address = private_ip-1
    },
    {
        address = private_ip-2
    },
    {
        address = private_ip-3
    }
]
```

I'm currently on terraform 0.11.5, null_resource appears to have been added in [0.6.7](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

There are limitations to the null_resource triggers though. interpolated variables can only result in strings. So, unfortunately you won't be able to interpolate a value that would result in a list or a map; for example:

```
resource "null_resource" "test" {
  triggers {
    mylist = "${var.addresses}"
  }
}
```

will result in an error

> Error: null_resource.test: triggers (address): '' expected type 'string', got unconvertible type '[]interface {}'

Comment: Actually, I'll probably use this to build out the list of tag blocks for use with my autoscaling group... sweet. Thank you for the question, it wasn't what I was initially looking for but it helped me find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

With terraform 10.8 you can

```
  output "private_subnets" { 
      value = [
          "${aws_subnet.private.*.id}"
      ]
   }
```

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/7430

Comment: Sorry, that was not what i was looking for. This only makes `private_subnets = [ address-list ] `
i want it to build a list of maps where the key in each map is the same. like
`private_subnets = [ { address : x1 } , { address : x2 } ... ]`