# Using ternary in terraform to choose between 2 different lists

Tags: terraform

I have two different lists `list_a` and `list_b` and I want to choose between them based on a value `local.server`

I've tried this and it doesn't work

```hcl
locals {
  server = "ubuntu"
  list_a = "${list("aaa")}"
  list_b = "${list("bbb")}"
  chosen = "${local.server == "ubuntu" ? local.list_a : local.list_b}"
}

output "chosen" {
  value = "${local.chosen}"
}
```

```sh
Error: Error asking for user input: 1 error(s) occurred:

* local.chosen: local.chosen: At column 3, line 1: conditional operator cannot be used with list values in:

${local.server == "ubuntu" ? local.list_a : local.list_b}
```

Comment: This will work in 0.12, but until then you cannot use list type returns in ternaries. See here for the workaround: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/18259#issuecomment-438407005. You have to cast the inner return from list to string and then recast the outer return back to list.

Comment: @MattSchuchard any idea on how to choose between a list of maps?

Comment: For a list of maps I used this reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/49565688/2965993

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Terraform v0.11, the conditional operator works only with primitive-typed values (strings, numbers, booleans). You can work around this by constructing a map with the two options and then conditionally choosing a key, as opposed to conditionally choosing a value:

```
locals {
  lists = {
    a = "${list("aaa")}"
    b = "${list("bbb")}"
  }
}

output "chosen" {
  value = "${local.lists[local.server == "ubuntu" ? "a" : "b"]}"
}
```

In the forthcoming (at the time of writing) Terraform v0.12 release, the conditional operator works with values of any type, as long as both the true and false expressions can be converted to the same type during type checking, so your original example would work but can be rewritten using the first-class expression syntax also introduced by v0.12:

```
locals {
  server = "ubuntu"
  list_a = ["aaa"]
  list_b = ["bbb"]
  chosen = local.server == "ubuntu" ? local.list_a : local.list_b
}

output "chosen" {
  value = local.chosen
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Interpolation only seems to work on strings so if we make the ternary expression return a string by joining an often unused character i.e. `|`

```hcl
delim  = "|"
chosen = "${local.server == "ubuntu" ?
         join(local.delim, local.list_a) :
         join(local.delim, local.list_b)}"
```

and then we can change the output to split on that same delimiter

```hcl
output "chosen" {
  value = "${split(local.delim, local.chosen)}"
}
```

```sh
✗ terraform apply

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

chosen = [
    aaa
]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice workaround for those still using terraform < 0.12.x:

You can use split to create a string from a list, evaluate ternary then join to make it a list again.

```
a = ["list", "values", "for ubuntu"]
b = ["list", "values", "for others"]

new_list = "${split(",", local.server == "ubuntu" ? join(",", local.a) : join(",", local.b))}"
```